# Async Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-modules, async.js

I have a problem with my for loop only one if block works.
I have to get the temperature from a whether API and put it back my table using my put method for every city.
The problem is that I can't fill all the cities.
How can i use ASYNC (https://caolan.github.io/async) module to make for loop work?
Here is my code :

```js
for (i in guests) {
        ville = i[ville_id];
        guest_id = i._id;
        if (ville) {
          results.push(req2 = http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + ville + ',france&APPID=xxx', function(res) {
            return res.on('data', function(chunk) {
              var options, test, url;
              test = chunk.toString();
              obj = JSON.parse(test);
              res = obj.main.temp;
              i[temp_id] = res;
              url = update_guest + guest_id.toString();
              options = {
                method: 'PUT',
                url: update_guest + guest_id,
                qs: {
                  api_key: 'xxx'
                },
                headers: {
                  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: {
                  '595f9b2a5ea9cb0004c21290': res
                },
                json: true
              };
              return request(options, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                  throw new Error(error);
                }
                return console.log(body);
              });
            });
          }));
        }
   }
```

Comment: You've stated that you want to use `async`. Why? If you want a single callback function to receive the results of all the ajax calls then you can use `async` to combine them together. But if each api call has its own row in the table then it's probably OK to use separate callbacks. (And it has the advantage that a single ajax failure won't destroy all the results.) In that case, read metalex9's answer. But also, I think you're confused about what `i` is. For example, instead of `ville = i[ville_id];` I think you want `ville = guests[i][ville_id];`.

Comment: The task mentioned that i had to use **async** .

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common issue in JavaScript due to the way [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) work. What is happening is your loop `for (i in guests)` is completed before any of your callbacks (`function(res){...}`) have a chance to run. Your callbacks reference variable `i`, but they don't "remember" what the value of `i` was when you made your HTTP request. Instead, when your callbacks execute, `i` will be whatever the last value in `guests` is since your `for...in` loop would have already completed by the time your callbacks are executed.

For example, let's say `guests` has two keys in it, `guest1` and `guest2`. Here's what would happen:

1. The first iteration of your loop runs. `i` is now `guest1`. The first HTTP request is fired.
2. The second iteration of your loop runs. `i` is now `guest2`. The second HTTP request is fired.
3. Both HTTP requests complete and your callbacks are executed, but `i` is set to `guest2`. As such, both callbacks references to `i` will be `guest2`.

What you need to do is find a way to give your callbacks access to the value of `i` *at the time your request was fired*. You could do this by creating your callbacks with a function that takes `i` as a parameter like so:

```
for (i in guests) {
    ville = i[ville_id];
    guest_id = i._id;
    if (ville) {
      results.push(req2 = http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + ville + ',france&APPID=xxx', (function (localI) { return function(res) {
        return res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          // removing code for clarity
          localI[temp_id] = res;
          // removing code for clarity
          return request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            // removing code for clarity
          });
        });
      })(i)));
    }
  }
```

You can read more about this approach [here](http://www.datchley.name/loop-variable-gotcha/).

What I've done is created a function which returns your callback and takes a parameter `localI`. I then immediately passed `i` as that parameter, returning a callback with `localI` set to the current value of `i`. Then I changed your reference to `i` inside the callback to `localI`. **Note that your references to `ville` and `guest_id` inside your callback will also have the same issue as `i`.** You'll either need to pass those as parameters as well or declare them inside your callback.